# How to filter the results from dynamic data with certain condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have certain dynamic data which contains file formats like .jpg, .png and other than that there will also be other formats like .zip, .rar, so here how can I filter and get only results of .jpg, .png and omit the results of zip and rar?

ex "data":"123.jpg"

```
  Results = {
    "data": [
      {
        "_score": 0.36464313,
        "_type": "data",
        "_id": "abcd",
        "_source": {
          "filter": "data",
          "information": {
            "product_id": "abcd",
            "creation_utctime": "1477335693653",
            "data":"123.jpg"
          },
          "enduser": "free"
        },
        "_index": "dell_laptop"
      },
      {
        "_score": 0.36464314,
        "_type": "data",
        "_id": "abcde",
        "_source": {
          "filter": "data",
          "information": {
            "product_id": "abcde",
            "creation_utctime": "1477335693653",
            "data":"123.png"
          },
          "enduser": "free"
        },
        "_index": "lenovo_laptop"
      },
      {
        "_score": 0.36464314,
        "_type": "data",
        "_id": "abcdef",
        "_source": {
          "filter": "data",
          "information": {
            "product_id": "abcde",
            "creation_utctime": "1477335693653",
            "data":"123.rar"
          },
          "enduser": "free"
        },
        "_index": "lenovo_laptop"
      },
       {
        "_score": 0.36464314,
        "_type": "data",
        "_id": "abcdef",
        "_source": {
          "filter": "data",
          "information": {
            "product_id": "abcde",
            "creation_utctime": "1477335693653",
            "data":"1235.zip"
          },
          "enduser": "free"
        },
        "_index": "lenovo_laptop"
      }
    ],

  }
```

Normally I am using this logic for getting nested values:

```
    this.rows=[];

    for (var res in this.Result) {
      var row = {};
      for (var key in this.Result[res]['_source']) {
        if (typeof this.Result[res]['_source'][key] === 'object') {
          for (var k in this.Result[res]['_source'][key]) {
            let temp = key + "." + k;
            row[temp] = this.Result[res]['_source'][key][k];
          }
        } else {
          row[key] = this.Result[res]['_source'][key]
        }
        row['_id'] = this.Result[res]['_id'];
      }
      this.rows.push(row);
    }
```

Comment: Use array filter with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array​.prototype​.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [String​.prototype​.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regular expression..

```js
let data= [
      {
        "_score": 0.36464313,
        "_type": "data",
        "_id": "abcd",
        "_source": {
          "filter": "data",
          "information": {
            "product_id": "abcd",
            "creation_utctime": "1477335693653",
            "data":"123.jpg"
          },
          "enduser": "free"
        },
        "_index": "dell_laptop"
      },
      {
        "_score": 0.36464314,
        "_type": "data",
        "_id": "abcde",
        "_source": {
          "filter": "data",
          "information": {
            "product_id": "abcde",
            "creation_utctime": "1477335693653",
            "data":"123.png"
          },
          "enduser": "free"
        },
        "_index": "lenovo_laptop"
      },
      {
        "_score": 0.36464314,
        "_type": "data",
        "_id": "abcdef",
        "_source": {
          "filter": "data",
          "information": {
            "product_id": "abcde",
            "creation_utctime": "1477335693653",
            "data":"123.rar"
          },
          "enduser": "free"
        },
        "_index": "lenovo_laptop"
      },
       {
        "_score": 0.36464314,
        "_type": "data",
        "_id": "abcdef",
        "_source": {
          "filter": "data",
          "information": {
            "product_id": "abcde",
            "creation_utctime": "1477335693653",
            "data":"1235.zip"
          },
          "enduser": "free"
        },
        "_index": "lenovo_laptop"
      }
    ]

  let result=data.filter(a=>a._source.information.data.match(/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i))
  console.log(result)
  // if you want to ignore some files do this
   let ignoredresult=data.filter(a=>!a._source.information.data.match(/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i))
   console.log("--------------------")
   console.log(ignoredresult)
```

Comment: ok here we are doing the match can we ignore certain file types as here for 3 types we entered so if there are more that 10 then

Comment: These 3 types will be available in the filtered result,if you want to add more just add them with `| `

Comment: instead of matching can we use the ignore case also ?